# Duda MySql workbench 8.0 y c# Cargar datos al servidor web cuando haya conexión a internet

Tags: c#, mysql

Como Poder trabajar de forma local host en mi base de datos cuando no tenga conexión a Internet, pero cuando regrese la conexión a Internet se actualice mi base de datos del servidor que sea lo mismo que tenga localmente lo tenga mi base de datos del servidor web.